# Angular 6 refresh Observable which fetches all entries from backend after delete

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have an Observable which fetches all data from my BackEnd. When I do a delete action on an item I want to refresh this observable.
I have tried two solutions that worked but it seems they are really ugly.
One was to force angular to reload the current route and the other was as shown in the below code to resubscribe the observable with a given interval

component.ts:

```
data: Observable<Setting[]>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.data = interval(1000).pipe(
    startWith(0),
    mergeMap(res => this.dataService.fetchData())
  );
}
```

I use the async pipe in a template to subscribe to my observable.

dataService.fetchData() looks like this:

```
fetchData() {
  const fetch$: Observable <Setting[]> = this.apiService.getSettings().pipe(share());
  fetch$.pipe(
    map(allSettings => this.subject$.next(allSettings))
  );

  return fetch$;
}
```

component.html:

```
<table>
  <tr *ngFor="let s of data | async">
    <td>{{s.property}}</td>
    <td>
      <button (click)="s = s = s.Id; delete(s)">Delete</button>
    </td>
</table>
```

As my last solution sends continuously GET requests to my backend, which is a waste of network traffic, anyone has an idea how to refresh my Observable with other techniques? Calling fetchData() after delete() doesn't update my view.. Even though when I refresh the view in browser(using F5), the changes appear.

EDIT:

objectService:

```
deleteSetting(keyName: string) {
  const x = this.apiService.delete(keyName);
  x.subscribe();
}
```

apiService:

```
delete(keyName: string): Observable<any> {
  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('keyName', keyName);

  return this.httpClient.delete<Setting>(this.API_URL + '/settings/delete', {params})
  .pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError('delete', []))
  );
}
```

delete() in component.ts:

```
deleteSetting() {
  this.settingsService.deleteSetting(this.keyNameToDelete);
  this.update.next(true);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make a get request right after the data is deleted? Or do you want to update the data locally without reaching out to the network?

Comment: Typically a delete request should send you the updated data back.

Comment: I don't think you can refresh the observable. When using HttpClient the observable completes after fetching the data. But you can directly run "this.dataService.fetchData()" when you delete the item. You can also create a Subject that will fire when a deletion is done and subscribe to that Subject to fetch the data.

Comment: I want to make a get request after data is deleted

Comment: @VinodBhavnani so if I call delete(object), it would instantiate a new GET Request to get the changed Context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use BehaviorSubject

> The BehaviorSubject has the characteristic that it stores the
>   “current” value. This means that you can always directly get the last
>   emitted value from the BehaviorSubject

When you delete make your BehaviorSubject value to true then subscribe the value inside ngOnInit

```
update=new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

ngOnInit() {
  this.fetchData();
  this.update.subscribe(update=>update === true ? this.fetchData() : '');
}

fetchData(){
      this.data = this.dataService.fetchData();
}
```

Inside delete method

```
deleteSetting(keyName: string) {
  const x = this.apiService.delete(keyName);
  x.subscribe(()=>this.update.next(true););
}
```

Comment: I guess your answer wil lead me to a good solution but now the delete call to BackEnd doesn't delete anything more. But it calls fetchData and reloads view.
why could this happen?
Maybe it is important to know that subject$ which is used inside dataService.fetchData() is already a BehaviourSubject

Comment: can you share your delete method?

Comment: added the methods from services above

Comment: works perfectly, just for clarification, could you explain this line of code from ngOnInit:
this.update.subscribe(update => update === true ? this.fetchData() : '');

Comment: basically i am using shorthand of if else. Initially set the update behaviour subject value to false at that time we no need to call this.fetchData()

Comment: so else would be '' , which means do nothing?

Comment: if it is false set it to null so that noting will happen